# how to sent cart items to paypal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I'm using mvc and I'm trying to send my entire cart to paypal. I can get it to add a single item but not the entire cart.

Here's my controller:

```
public ActionResult PostToPayPal(Cart cart, ShippingDetails shippingInfo)
{
    PayPal paypal = new PayPal();
    paypal.cmd = "_xclick";
    paypal.business = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BusinessAccountKey"];

    bool useSandbox = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseSandBox"]);
    if (useSandbox)
        ViewBag.actionURL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    else
    {
        ViewBag.actionURL = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    }

    paypal.cancel_return = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CancelURL"];
    paypal.@return = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReturnURL"];
    paypal.notify_url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NotifyURL"];

    paypal.currency_code = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CurrencyCode"];

    foreach (var lines in cart.Lines )
    {
        paypal.item_name = lines.Product.Name;
        paypal.amount = lines.Product.Price.ToString("c");
    }
    //paypal.item_name = item;
    //paypal.amount = amount;
    return View(paypal);

}
```

Here is my view:

```
@model SportsStore.Domain.Entities.PayPal

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PostToPayPal";
}

<h2>PostToPayPal</h2>

        <form id="frm" action="@ViewBag.actionURL">

                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cmd)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.business)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.no_shipping)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.@return)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cancel_return)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.notify_url)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.currency_code)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.item_name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.amount)

            <p>
                <h4>redirecting to paypal...</h4>
            </p>



        </form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(this.document).ready(function () {
        var frm = $("form");
        frm.submit();
    })
</script>
```

Here is my cart:

@model SportsStore.WebUI.Models.CartIndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Little Bow Peep: Your Cart";
}

### Your Cart

```
<table width="90%" align="center">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="center">Quantity</th>
            <th align="left">Item</th>
            <th align="right">Price</th>
            <th align="right">Subtotal</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach(var line in Model.Cart.Lines)
        {
            <tr>
                <td align="center">@line.Quantity</td>
                <td align="left">@line.Product.Name</td>
                <td align="right">@line.Product.Price.ToString("c")</td>
                <td align="right">@((line.Quantity * line.Product.Price).ToString("c"))</td>
                <td>
                    @using(Html.BeginForm("RemoveFromCart", "Cart"))
                    {
                        @Html.Hidden("ProductId", line.Product.ProductID)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ReturnUrl)
                        <input class="actionButtons" type="submit" value="Remove"/>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="right">Total:</td>
            <td align="right">
                @Model.Cart.ComputeTotalValue().ToString("c")
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

</table>

<p align="center" class="actionButtons">
    <a href="@Model.ReturnUrl">Continue Shopping</a>
    @Html.ActionLink("Checkout now", "Checkout")
</p>
```

Code for cart entitie:

```
private readonly List<CartLine> lineCollection = new List<CartLine>();

public IEnumerable<CartLine> Lines
{
    get { return lineCollection; }
}

public void AddItem(Product product, int quantity)
{
    CartLine line = lineCollection
        .Where(p => p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (line == null)
    {
        lineCollection.Add(new CartLine {Product = product, Quantity = quantity});
    }
    else
    {
        line.Quantity += quantity;
    }
}

public void RemoveLine(Product product)
{
    lineCollection.RemoveAll(l => l.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID);
}

public decimal ComputeTotalValue()
{
    return lineCollection.Sum(e => e.Product.Price*e.Quantity);
}

public void Clear()
{
    lineCollection.Clear();
}
```

}

public class CartLine
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

any help ???

Thanks...

Comment: You are taking the price from the cart that gets passed in to your call?  Please tell me the client just passes in an item id and you have a custom binder that builds a cart lines on the server side (for some reason..?)?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but my Cart object contains the values that the user added to their cart. So I pass that object into my controller.

Comment: i've edited it to show my Cart entitie

Comment: I think what Shane is asking is if the data you receive from the client's shopping cart includes the item price that you use to calculate their total. This is dangerous, because the data coming from the client is untrustworthy - you should look up the prices independently on the server side before calculating the amount to charge.

Comment: oh, okay. no it's not doing that. thanks,